# WPF HierarchicalDataTemplate treeview

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have some objects I would like to display using a `TreeView`.
The classes I use are defined like this:

```
public abstract class QueryPart
{
    private static Random _random;
    protected static Random Random { get { return _random??(_random=new Random(654)); } }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public QueryPart()
    {
        this.Name = this.GetType().Name + " " + Random.Next();
    }       
}

public abstract class Criterium : QueryPart
{        
    object ParamValue { get; set; }
    protected Criterium()
    {
        ParamValue = Random.Next();
    }
}

public sealed class Criterium<T> : QueryPart
{             
}

public abstract class CriteriumGroup : QueryPart
{
    public ObservableCollection<QueryPart> Childeren { get; private set; }
    public CriteriumGroup()
    {
        Childeren = new ObservableCollection<QueryPart>();
    }
}

public sealed class CriteriumGroup<T> : CriteriumGroup
{        
}

public static class Helper
{
    public static CriteriumGroup<T> GetDefaultCriteriumGroup<T>()
    {
        var master = new CriteriumGroup<T>();
        master.Childeren.Add(new Criterium<T>());
        var sub = new CriteriumGroup<T>()
        {
            Childeren =
                {
                    new Criterium<T>(),
                    new Criterium<T>(),
                    new Criterium<T>(),
                    new CriteriumGroup<T>() 
                    {
                        Childeren =
                        {
                            new Criterium<T>(), 
                            new Criterium<T>(), 
                            new Criterium<T>()
                        }
                    },
                    new Criterium<T>()
                }
        };
        master.Childeren.Add(sub);
        sub = new CriteriumGroup<T>()
        {
            Childeren =
                {
                    new Criterium<T>(),
                    new CriteriumGroup<T>() 
                    {
                        Childeren =
                        {
                            new Criterium<T>(), 
                            new Criterium<T>(), 
                            new Criterium<T>()
                        }
                    },
                }
        };
        master.Childeren.Add(sub);
        return master;
    }
}
```

I would bind the `TreeView` to an instance of `CriteriumGroup<T>`, and use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.
The problem is, I can't seem to get it right - my `TreeView.Items.Count` is always **0**.

This is what I have so far:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeview" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootCriteriumGroup}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DynamicLinq:QueryPart}">
                <local:QueryPartModelView2/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DynamicLinq:Criterium}" ItemsSource={Binding Path=Childeren}>
                <local:QueryPartModelView2/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                              DataType="{x:Type DynamicLinq:CriteriumGroup}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Childeren}">
                <local:QueryPartModelView2/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I can't seem to get it right" is not an accurate description of the problem.

Comment: Is RootCriteriumGroup an instance of CriteriumGroup<T> or is it a collection? ItemsSource needs to be bound to an IEnumerable<T>, otherwise your binding won't work afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Taking an approach like this works:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyEnumerableProperty}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding MyImageUri}"  />
                <TextBlock x:Name="someName" Text="{Binding MyNodeText}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

This is a simple way to start, once you have it working you can then look to move things around and have them as Styles and Templates in Resource sections.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @xorcrud, it does work, it is a stripped down version of something from one of  my own projects. This means the problem likely lies with your DataContext - if this isn't set up correctly there will be no data to bind. Try checking your Output window in the IDE for binding errors when the app is running, it may give you some valuable clues. In any case there isn't enough code above to trace the exact problem.

Comment: DataContext is fine. No BindingExpression path errors or other stuff in the debug output.
I'm starting to think there's a problem with using generics, or abstract base classes...